# Changing the url in WSDL generated interface

Tags: c#, wsdl, uri, webrequest

To start off, i have never coded a SOAP web request before in my life so this has been a learning curve of note.

I am busy writing a service that will make a soap request to a SageX3 web interface in C#. Net (obviously using Visual Studio).  We already have similar request on another service that is supposedly working and I am using that as a reference. So took the (supposedly) same wsdl file and created a connected service reference that generated the Reference.cs file which should be the interface I must use to this soap request.  But this request url uses a default url that I do not seem to be able to change.  I have looked through the class definition and the properties in the interface like "endpoint" and such all seem to be read only.  So I looked in the other project how that Refenrence.cs file looks which is completely different.  The first part of my generated reference.cs looks like this:

Newly created reference.cs header:

[image]

If you look at the original reference.cs file, it is vastly different:

Original created reference.cs header:

[image]

What I notice is that the original has public class that also inherits from SoapHttpClientProtocol that will allow the user of that class to setup the url as reqiured.  I do not have that option as my generated code is straight up an interface.

This brings me to my question, could it be that I have an invalid wsdl file or working from a different file as the original code?

Was the code generated differently as there might be a different tool used in Visual Studio?

Did the original author make changes to the reference.cs after it was generated?  I think this is a possible answer that I need to add a class definition in the reference.cs file.

Or am I on the completely wrong track here.

Comment: Look in the error or output window to check for any errors or warning messages. Try to debug things by 1) feeding the WSDL to [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/tools/soapui/) and see if it is parsed successfully and you can generate sample requests from it, and 2) instead of a reference from Visual Studio, try using [svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe) to generate code and see if something differs.